# getParent() on Fragment View returns null in onResume() after rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, onresume

I have the following code in `onResume()` in a custom fragment that extends `ListFragment`, which tries to find its parent:

```java
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    System.out.println("resume");
    View view = getView();
    System.out.println("view is " + (view != null ? "not " : "" ) + "null");
    ViewParent parent = view != null ? view.getParent() : null;
    System.out.println("parent is " + (parent != null ? "not " : "" ) + "null");
    if(view != null) {
        System.out.println(view.getRootView());
    }
}
```

When I run the app initially in the emulator it prints:

```
I/System.out: resume
I/System.out: view is not null
I/System.out: parent is not null
I/System.out: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{ ... }
```

However, after rotating the emulator, it prints:

```
I/System.out: resume
I/System.out: view is not null
I/System.out: parent is null
I/System.out: android.widget.FrameLayout{ ... }
```

Even though the fragment is visible just fine in the app, it appears as though it's view is not properly attached into the view tree yet in `onResume()` after rotating, since the root view is the `FrameLayout` which is the root view of the fragment and not the root view of the app.

What could be the cause of this and how can I properly access its `ViewParent` in/after `onResume()`, without resorting to something line `getActivity().findViewById(someId)`?

---

**edit:**

When I adjust the code in `onResume()` to print the root view in the next frame (using `View.post()`), it *does* find the proper root view (which means I can access the parent):

```java
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    System.out.println("resume");
    View view = getView();
    System.out.println("view is " + (view != null ? "not " : "" ) + "null");
    ViewParent parent = view != null ? view.getParent() : null;
    System.out.println("parent is " + (parent != null ? "not " : "" ) + "null");
    if(view != null) {
        System.out.println(view.getRootView());
        
        /**
         * added to see if it finds the proper root view in the next frame 
         */
        view.post(() -> {
            System.out.println("how about after post?");
            System.out.println(view.getRootView());
        });
    }
}
```

Now it prints:

```
I/System.out: view is not null
I/System.out: parent is null
I/System.out: android.widget.FrameLayout{ ... }
I/System.out: how about after post?
I/System.out: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{ ... }
```

But utilizing `View.post()` like that just feels like a nasty hack.

---

**edit:**

So, it appears the order of operations is not as I would have expected (might be a bug?).

But I may have found a solution, which I will post as an answer if it works as intended. The idea is to add a `View.OnAttachStateChangeListener` to the fragment view in `onViewCreated()` and thus find the parent in `View.OnAttachStateChangeListener.onViewAttachedToWindow()` instead of in `Fragment.onResume()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue by moving my logic from `onResume()` into an `View.OnAttachStateChangeListener` that I add in `onViewCreated()`:

```java
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            System.out.println(view.getParent());
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {
            view.removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this);
        }
    };
}
```

Now it behaves as I intended.

The take-away is that `onResume()` is not a reliable method in which to assume the fragment view is attached to the view tree already.

Comment: You may create global context inside fragment and override onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) method and define context with view.getContext(). Then you can use that context in onResume method.

Comment: @S.Grain I don't understand how your comment is relevant to my question or my answer. I need the parent view of a fragment view, not the context.

Comment: Terribly sorry.I just got it wrong.